# How come types from Assemblies cannot be Resolved Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, assemblies

Windsor castle cannot Resolve any type after registering them by Assembly

I am trying implement a service that scans the current library for all '.ddl' extension and then registering them by Assembly in Castle Windsor, but when i try to resolve An exception is thrown with the message : 'No component for supporting the service'. If i iterate through Kernel.GetAssignableHandlers i can see that all types are registered.

***1. get the assembly root name:***

```
var delimiterIndex = assembly.FullName.IndexOfAny(new[] { '.' });
```

***2. Get all the Assemblies as an Array***

```
return Directory.EnumerateFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                       .Where(x => Path.GetExtension(x).Equals(".dll", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                         .Where(x => Path.GetFileName(x)
                            .StartsWith(rootAssemblyName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Select(Assembly.LoadFile).ToArray();
```

***3. Register each Assembly in Windsor Castle Container***

```
Classes.FromAssembly(assembly).Pick().WithServiceBase().WithServiceAllInterfaces().WithServiceSelf().LifestyleTransient()
```

***4. Resolve***

```
var instance = _container.Resolve<IFoo>();
```

When Resolving 'ComponentNotFoundException' is thrown with the message:

> 'No component for supporting the service Mes.Utils.DBUpgrade.IDBUpgrader was found'

Comment: I would rather don't use this approach (locate implementation via searching through many dlls), instead I would register concrete implementation per interface. If it's difficult to implement, imagine problems to troubleshoot production issues, should such take place.

Comment: Is it possible that you've registered all of the types that you directly need to work with, but one of those depends on `IDBUpgrader` which isn't registered? Are you able to resolve other types from the assembly?

Comment: You make an Excellent point. I tried running and ResolveAll(typeOf(object)) which threw an unsatisfied exception on a Custom Exception, due to a string argument in the constructor. Excluding the Expception type from the registration allows me to call a Resolve all on type of object succesfully, and if iterate through the returned array and call GetType(),  it is the correct types that are returned, but if i try a single resolve, it still fails. If there are unsatified Dependencies, wouldn't the exception be thrown upwards?

Comment: The assembly array is filled, through the debugger in can see that the container have the types registered, and have no unsatisfied dependencies. But i think that i will give Classes.FromAssemblyInDirectory() a try, to be honest i missed that one in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

I never manage to find the actual error in the actual code, but Krzysztof Kozmic suggested to use `Classes.FromAssemblyNamed` instead of `Classes.FromAssembly` which works great :D

so the change made to the original code compare to that showed in section 3 is as shown : `Classes.FromAssemblyNamed(assembly.FullName).Pick().WithServiceBase().WithServiceAllInterfaces().WithServiceSelf().LifestyleTransient()`.

i guess that the problem somehow was the way i loaded the assemblies, but castle windsor manage to load them probably

Thank you all the answers and discussion in the comments  :D